# How to handle scaling when request per minute go from 500 to 5000 instanly

Tags: scaling

I have an application that spikes from 500 rpm to 5000 and stays there for 20-30min. I know that's not a ton of requests but its the magnitude of the jump that is killing me. AWS-EC2 takes 5 min to scale up so that's not helpful when things move so fast.  Maybe multiple DB's that handle different pieces of the application.

How would you go about analyzing this and thinking about infrastructure if you will always go from 500 to 5000RPM or higher in one minute?

This is the graph from my AWS logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can predict that demand will increase at some point you can automate provisioning of new instances. If you can't determine this then you need to do proper capacity planning. For instance, how many servers/containers do you need running to sustain the load with an acceptable user experience?  This will be key to determine.

You also should look at implement asynchronous messaging patterns that offload the spike although this may come with some performance degradation.

One additional consideration would be moving to a serverless architecture like AWS Lambda. This likely wouldn't fully solve the problem but would provide you more ability to quickly provision on demand infrastructure.